# What is preferred and less in total weight - CSS3 Gradients/Box Shadow or Sprites?

Tags: html, css, gradient

I am constructing a mobile web app with a requirement of offline use.  I am beginning to worry about total weight in code/files.

What is your experience with CSS3 (gradients/box shadow) vs. sprites, is one preferred but heavier?  I am going to do some benchmarking but wanted to gather some information before I began.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 properties are almost always preferred. They don't require an extra HTTP request, and are easier to edit in your text editor, as well as play around with in Firebug/Web Inspector.

However, if you start combining many of these properties together, they can hog down a system pretty much, since they are being computed on the device. So don't overdo it - if you need real fancy stuff, you might be better off using a sprite.